# Что означают лишние звенья в ссылке на класс?

Tags: java, android

Есть [проект](https://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/browse/OpenGPSTracker/application/src/nl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/util/Constants.java?name=release_1.3.5) там ссылка в Constants.java

```
public static final String SERVICENAME = "nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker.intent.action.GPSLoggerService";
```

Все хорошо но, откуда взялось это `.intent.action.` в ссылке, я проверял такого пути не существует в проекте, хоть такой класс и есть.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, SERVICENAME);
```

Это просто название для `newWakeLock`

тут может быть любое значение. Они просто использовали путь класса и слова action

[посмотрите тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   ..screen will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```